# Rails 3.1 error 406 response when downloading web fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, font-face, compass-sass, spree, webfonts

I'm having problems serving web fonts through Rails 3.1, within a Spree 0.70 application using compass (which I don't think should make a difference)

I have a scss file which contains the declarations:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'RokkittRegular';
  src: font_url('fonts/store/rokkitt-font/Rokkitt-webfont.eot');
  src: local('Rokkitt Regular'),
    font_url('fonts/store/rokkitt-font/Rokkitt-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    font_url('fonts/store/rokkitt-font/Rokkitt-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    font_url('fonts/store/rokkitt-font/Rokkitt-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    font_url('fonts/store/rokkitt-font/Rokkitt-webfont.svg#RokkittRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

These declarations are successfully included in the outputted css, and the font files themselves are stored in:

```
/app/assets/fonts/store/rokkitt-font/
```

and contain:

- Rokkitt-webfont.eot
- Rokkitt-webfont.svg
- Rokkitt-webfont.ttf
- Rokkitt-webfont.woff

But when i visit the site the fonts aren't rendered. I've tried visiting the files directly and I don't get a response. I would've expected the browser to try and download the file, but instead all I get is an error 406 response. Other assets in the stylesheets, such as images render correctly. Can anyone help me diagnose this? I was thinking it might be something to do with Mime-types, although I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use font_url or other rails 3.1 asset helpers you don't need the asset type - in this case: 'fonts' - in the url. So the urls should have been:

```
font_url('store/rokkitt-font/Rokkitt-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
font_url('store/rokkitt-font/Rokkitt-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
font_url('store/rokkitt-font/Rokkitt-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
font_url('store/rokkitt-font/Rokkitt-webfont.svg#RokkittRegular') format('svg');
```

Which solves the problem. Hope this helps anyone else who comes across this problem.

Guess i'm still getting used to the asset pipeline... chalk this one up as a school boy mistake!